# How can I solve WordPad not being a "valid Win32 application"?

Tags: wordpad

Somehow in trying to cleanup my computer's hard drive, I have inadvertently corrupted WordPad, which I have long used for viewing many types of files, including logs (i.e., log4j).

Now, when I right click one of these files and choose "Open with" and "WordPad", I get an error:

> fn is not a valid Win32 application).

I've researched this issue, tried reinstalling `wordpad.exe`, but I still get the same error.

Comment: This isn't programming related, should be moved to SuperUser

Comment: is *"fn is not a valid Win32 application"* the actual error text?  sounds like you've corrupted the file association or other registry keys, not the actual WordPad application.  not sure how you'd fix it though.

Comment: Substituted "fn" for the actual file name, but otherwise the message is accurate. Suspect you are correct about corrupting something other than the application, which still works. It's the right click and open with that doesn't work now. Don't have any idea how to fix whatever is causing this problem.
Notepad is okay, but I prefer Wordpad because it doesn't "wrap" lines.

Comment: @user31546 you can disable word wrap in Notepad, just uncheck "Word Wrap" under the *Format* tab.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you an alternative like [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm)